# How to match all the uppercase letters in python regex?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, python-unicode

I need to match some names with regex in python, I am having troubles with non-ASCII uppercase letters:

Here an example list of names:

1. Gonzalo
2. Éder
3. Porto

But using the classic ´A-Z´ does not work obviously, because Éder is ignored.

How can I match all the non ASCII uppercase letters?

In ruby one can with `/[[:upper:]]/`, more info [here](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.1.4/Regexp.html).